# position:absolute in media query is overriding all other rules

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a basic responsive design using [bootstrap.](http://getbootstrap.com/) I am simply trying give absolute positioning to an element in one viewport, and something else in all other view ports,  but it's overriding all of the rules in other view ports.

Here are the main rules.

```
 .start-today  {
    color:#fffeaf;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top:40px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    -moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
.start-today a {
       color:#fffeaf;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    -moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
```

Here are the rules in the smallest viewport that is overriding the main rule and all other view port rules.

```
  @media only screen and (min-width:320px) {

.start-today {
        color:#fffeaf;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 0.3px;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute; bottom:100px; left:2px;
        }
        .start-today a {
            font-size:12px;
        }

}
```

Comment: you need to add `position: relative;` or a other in your `.start-today` from the main code so it has a fall back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the media query raises the specificity of the rule. The alternative would be to add your `position: absolute` rule in the base styles (outside of any media queries) and then remove it in a media query when you no longer want it to apply. For example, if you wanted to stop absolutely positioning the element at 500px:

```
// Set your initial rule:
.start-today {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 2px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .start-today {
        // reset your rules here:
        position: relative;
        bottom: auto;
        left: auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `min-width: 320px` and I do not know of any screens smaller then `320px` so that query will always be triggered.

try changing the `min` to `max` or adjust the `px`

like this: `@media only screen and (max-width:320px)`

or this: `@media only screen and (min-width:720px)`

All other queries will need to be set back from `absolute` to `relative`

like this: `position: relative;`

Answer (score 1):

Using a `min-width` of 320px, the styles will be applied to viewports with width 320px or greater.

Did you perhaps mean to use a `max-width` of 320px so that the absolute positioning is only applied to viewports of 320px or less?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
 @media only screen and (max-width:320px)
```

**max not min**

so it will apply to size less than 320 ,,,,
in your current cast it apply to all sized more than 320